# Diffentiating a gravity field to get the radius from a planet center as a function of time

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, free-fall

I'm trying to solve a differential equation to get the radius from a planet as a function of time during a free fall.

$$
g=\frac{d^2r}{dt^2}=\frac{GM}{r^2}.
$$

Is this statement true?

$$
[r^3]d^2=GM(dt)^2
$$

If so how would I integrate this two times to the radius as a function of time. If not how would I correctly setup this equation so that I could integrate this properly? Could I instead use r(dr)^2.

$$
r(dr)^2=GM(dt)^2
$$

$$
r^3=3GMt^2
$$

**Edit:**
I see what I did wrong. It should be like this.

$$
a=\frac{dv}{dx}v=\frac{-GM}{x^2}
$$

Rearrange and integrate to the get the velocity as a function of position.

$$
dx=vdt
$$

$$
\int \frac{1}{v}dx= t
$$

Substitute velocity with the velocity function and integrate to get the time. And then rearrange to the get radius as a function of time.

I've only taken one semester of calculus at the high school level, so I'm not really good at solving more complicated integrations and differential equations yet.

Comment: Surely there's an error, if you rearrange things you would get $$r^2\frac{d^2r}{dt^2} = GM$$

Comment: So r^4 = 6GMt^2?

Comment: @Andre: you can't just double integrate as you are doing.

Comment: This is really more of a question about how to solve second-order ODEs than it is a question about physics.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I agree but that's mainly because OP's math is a little weird. W/o that issue it would be a physics question  (but not a very clear one)

Comment: *Is this statement true?* No. It is not even meaningful. What is $d^2$ supposed to mean?

Comment: I may be interpreting this incorrectly, but it looks like you’re manipulating the $d$ as though it’s a variable and cancelling it from both sides of your expressions. If this is the case, then you must learn calculus before understanding what these expressions mean and how to manipulate them. For instance, your first expression may be better written as $r’’=GM/r^2$, where the double prime denotes a second derivative.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just 'double integrate' the way you're doing.

If, as you claim:

$$g=\frac{\text{d}^2r}{\text{d}t^2}$$

$$\frac{\text{d}^2r}{\text{d}t^2}=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\Big(\frac{\text{d}r}{\text{d}t}\Big)$$

with $g$ a constant, this means that:

$$\frac{\text{d}r}{\text{d}t}=gt+c_1$$

and:

$$r(t)=\frac12 gt^2+c_1t+c_2$$

where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are integration constants, to be determined from initial conditions.

Comment: I don’t think the OP is integrating - or indeed knows what integrating actually is. It looks to me like they’re manipulating the $d$ like a variable and e.g. cancelling it from both sides of their expression.

Comment: @J.Murray Yep. Something like that...